# Catching STDOUT and STDERR with pipes on next command as separated arguments?

Tags: shell, pipe, stdout, stdin, stderr

Is it possible to have a command to catch both STDOUT and STDERR as separated streams to use as arguments in the next command?

An example of it would be.

```
# foo outputs to stdout and stderr
# bar recieves in -i and -j streams that could be files but in general they are streams, so it would make sence to pipe to any of this two. 
$ foo | bar -i - -j -&2
```

Can I do this in bash? or in some other shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the help of named pipes:

```
mkfifo /tmp/whatever
foo 2>/tmp/whatever | bar -i - -j /tmp/whatever
```

No data actually gets written to `/tmp/whatever`. The kernel sends the writing process's output straight to the reading process.